# Access HTML5 local storage from Angular2

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, local-storage

I'm following this tutorial: https://medium.com/@blacksonic86/authentication-in-angular-2-958052c64492 about authentication in Angular2.

I've the issue with this part:

`import localStorage from 'localStorage';`

I've read somewhere else that I should use this library https://github.com/marcj/angular2-localstorage to access local storage in HTML5. Is it really the only option? Can I access HTML5 local storage from angular2 without using extra modules?

Comment: You do not need to import anything, `localStorage` is a builtin browser feature and it's part of the [lib.d.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L18564).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `localStorage` directly in your service without `import localStorage from 'localStorage';`.

Comment: sounds awesome. Than I guess this import localStorage in unnecessary in the tutorial and is simply a mistake?

Comment: yes, i have already used `localStorage` directly in one of my service.

Comment: @ranakrunal9 how did this work out with the testing? Did it work okay?

Comment: The alternative is to introduce a storage interface and unit test with a mock implementation I guess.

Answer (score 7):

You should use directly `localStorage`, as mentioned by other here, it is a builtin browser features ([supported browser](http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage)).

Additionally I am adding below few examples on how to add an entry in it (they work both in the same way).

```
localStorage.colorSetting = '#a4509b';    // dot notation
localStorage['colorSetting'] = '#a4509b'; // bracket notation
localStorage.setItem('colorSetting', '#a4509b');
```

As a note, `angular2-localstorage` works on top of native `localStorage` and provide a "convenient" way to save and restore automatically a variable state in your directive.

Comment: how did you manage the error handling with typescript?  'Cannot find name 'localStorage'.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that the local storage project is seeking someone to takeover and is not currently being maintained.  So I am not going to use it until then.  I was able to find the a fix in my **tsconfig.json** file.

In the property lib you can simply add **dom**

```
"lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
```

This is supported in the compiler options https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html.

I had to restart visual studio code for this to remove the errors.